# Why is statement about area between curves false?

Tags: calculus

My book says the statement if "$\int_a^b [f(x)-g(x)] dx=-10$ then the area between the curves $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ from $a$ to $b$ is $10$" is false. But intuitively it seems true. $f(x)$ is the lower function because the equation gives $-10$. The area between the curves is $10$ because we are just looking at the absolute value of this $-10$. So why is it false?

Comment: The curves can cross. Maybe $f$ is on top at the beginning, but between $a$ and $b$ they cross, and then $f$ is on the bottom. So the area could be $20$ before they cross, and then the area is $30$ after they cross, but counts as negative.

Comment: @user532874 , what book is this from?

Comment: Before performing out such integration, you must ensure that f > g in [a,b], otherwise, you have to break [a,b] to a smaller range where f > g. This would avoid the situation @Nick correctly stated.

Comment: @user532874 if you are satisfied with your answer, then please click the green check to close the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets call $g$ the "upper" function and $f$ the "lower" function since you already have an intuition for what this means. Now, imagine we are integrating over the interval $[a,b]$... as long as $g>f$, then the area being computed by the integral is positive. But, if the two functions intersect and suddenly $f>g$, then the area being computed by the integral is negative. On the interval $[a,b]$, the integral is adding all of these positive and negative areas together. So really the integral returns the "net difference" in the area between two functions on the interval $[a,b]$. The sum of the total positive area and the total negative area between the two functions could be $40 + -50 = -10$. But the actual area between the two curves is $|40| + |-50| = 40 + 50 = 90$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function $$f(x)=5\sin x$$

Note that $$\int _{\pi}^{4\pi} 5\sin x\ dx = -10$$

while the area between the graph and the $x$-axis is  $$ A=\int _{\pi}^{4\pi} |5\sin x |\ dx = 30$$